# Timeout while writing to the queue-based output stream

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

My GAE application works fine but at some point it throws the error below. I am trying to figure out what could be the root cause of a `Timeout while writing to the queue-based output stream error`:

```
java.io.IOException: Timeout while writing to the queue-based output stream
    org.restlet.engine.io.PipeStream$2.write(PipeStream.java:99)
    java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    com.dropbox.core.util.IOUtil.copyStreamToStream(IOUtil.java:52)
    com.dropbox.core.util.IOUtil.copyStreamToStream(IOUtil.java:63)
    com.dropbox.core.util.IOUtil.copyStreamToStream(IOUtil.java:34)
    com.dropbox.core.v1.DbxClientV1$Downloader.copyBodyAndClose(DbxClientV1.java:535)
    com.dropbox.core.v1.DbxClientV1.getFile(DbxClientV1.java:427)
    com.myapp.MyServerResource.getFile(MyServerResource.java:268)
    com.myapp.MyServerResource$1.write(MyServerResource.java:140)
    org.restlet.engine.io.IoUtils$2.run(IoUtils.java:537)
    org.restlet.engine.Engine$1.run(Engine.java:158)
    com.google.appengine.tools.development.RequestThreadFactory$1$1$2.run(RequestThreadFactory.java:110)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    com.google.appengine.tools.development.RequestThreadFactory$1$1.run(RequestThreadFactory.java:107)
```

Is this really timeout issue with the URL fetch or an issue with output stream copy?

Comment: em, the root cause is `com.google.appengine.tools.development.RequestThreadFactory$1$1.run(RequestThreadFactory.java:107)`, if it's not truncated

Comment: I think I need to rephrase my question, I mean what could be causing this error randomly.

Comment: then you need to provide more information, your code, usage pattern, etc. Current stacktrace doesn't say anything possible cause